# Hyperplanes in general position with respect to hypersurface

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $X$  be a hypersurface of degree $d \geq 2$ in $\mathbb P^n$. Then what is the meaning of the following statement:

> Let $H$ be a plane in *general position* with respect to $X$

$(i)$ Does *general position*  mean that $H$ is not contained in $X$ and $H \cap X$ regular at every point? (I know the definition of general linear position but I failed to find the general position definition in this context.)

$(ii)$ Does Bertini's theorem ensure that such an $H$ always exists?

Any help from anyone is welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

General position always means that the object that we are searching lives in a open and dense set. In our case it means "transversality" and it implies that the intersection $X\cap H$ is as good as it can be.

If we assume that $X$ is smooth then it is exactly what is predicted in the statement of Bertini's theorem (at least in Hartshorne's book). The set $B$ of "bad" hyperplanes $H$ such that $X\cap H$ is not regular at some point is Zariski closed in the parameter space of hyperplanes. The deal of the theorem is to prove that $B$ is not the whole parameter space.